# navigation w/o map

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently trying to run a navigation (on move_base) w/o global map (I've set blank map on map_server). I don't want SLAM for now, so my idea for now is to navigate through easy-to-get-to points on planned path. I am trying to change global planner for carrot_planner, but maybe there is a better option for that kind of navigation (other planner or maybe something what will replace the move_base node).

edit:
there can be a local map from laser scan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119226/navigation-w/o-map/) by [BP](https://answers.ros.org/users/10951/bp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2014-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're navigating without a map, then your robot will only be using distances and bearings to get to places. Therefore the robot will need to measure distance and bearings. To get to different waypoints it would be simply geometry to get to one point or another with the accuracy depending on how well your robot tracked its path (dead reckoning).

If there is not SLAM or map then the idea of a planner is redundant. The robot just needs a start point and a list of navigation points that can be determined in relation to the start point.

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2014-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BP](https://answers.ros.org/users/10951/bp/) on 2014-01-20**:
Yes, but:

1. I want path to be smooth
2. I want to avoid obstacles
3. In the future there will be sth like SLAM (i hope) but different than normal (semantic rather than metric). But i have to do simple navigation first.

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2014-01-20**:
If you want path smoothing, research cubic splines.Trajectory controllers in ROS_Control also use them. If you want to avoid obstacles, apart from bumping your way around them, you'll need some sort of map and path planning, google (approx) cell decomposition and octomap. Try orienteering w/o a map.

**Comment by [BP](https://answers.ros.org/users/10951/bp/) on 2014-01-21**:
i forgot to mention that there can be a local map (i try to run it under move_base). What You are telling me is good, but it requires (i suppose) a lot of work, when move base has built in local planner, smoothing, dynamic window etc. I just don't want to have global map, which (I hope) I'll add in the future.

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2014-01-21**:
I think you're on a good track, if you haven't used move base before, maybe try using it on a simulator in its default most basic state before trying to customise the configuration. Keep it as simple as possible get it working and build from there.